# JQuery autocomplete distinct suggestion and another suggestion based on input value using JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm trying to fetch data using json file and jquery, my script works fine but the problem is the array with the same value also displaying on autocomple suggestion. I tried a lot of approach like reduce method but no luck, it shows only 1 location. I also want to make autocomplete suggestion inside suggestion, you can see on the photo what I'm trying to achieve and what I have achieved so far. Can you please give me an idea on how to do that because I'm newbie on json data fetching and it's not easy like how it is using database and server-side language like PHP.

[image: Image Actual Result]

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#check-in').hide();
$('#lets-go').hide();

var arrayReturn = [];
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "locprop.json",
async: true,
success: function (data) {
 for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
 var id = (data[i].id).toString();
 arrayReturn.push({'value' : data[i].location, 'data' : id});
}

var uniqueCity = Array.from(arrayReturn.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj.location, obj),new Map()).values());
                                
         console.log(uniqueCity);
         loadSuggestions(uniqueCity);
        }
      });

       function loadSuggestions(options) {
        $('#destination').autocomplete({
       lookup: options,

       onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        $('#destination').html(suggestion.value);
        $('#check-in').show();
        $('#lets-go').show();                       }
     });
    }
 });
</script>
```

MY JSON FILE

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "location": "El Nido",
    "property": "El Nido Hotel 1",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1s1GOpqujbUbBXaSde5He29jO0aWWrK9C",
    "body": "This is Elnido Hotel 1"
  },
  { 
    "id": 2,
    "location": "El Nido",
    "property": "El Nido Hotel 2",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Kdyrq5qLXgL8Cwuz1Ekz6gUyj7qhczHp",
    "body": "This is Elnido Hotel 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "location": "El Nido",
    "property": "El Nido Hotel 3",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=16fiBYsg-9o9kPhkzMaeFU5J2mH9Lk4be",
    "body": "This is Elnido Hotel 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "location": "Boracay",
    "property": "Boracay Hotel 1",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=13XG6Vjr2wbqwxfO_HG1K1NhFJPzsfG_K",
    "body": "This is Boracay Hotel 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "location": "Boracay",
    "property": "Boracay Hotel 2",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1IMg1e8f8b_znWs_57VrNzN6RumbWpadm",
    "body": "This is Boracay Hotel 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "location": "Davao",
    "property": "Davao Hotel 1",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1fOiTOp5AEjJf0-r75S8C4Bz4im24LssS",
    "body": "This is Davao Hotel 1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code does not seem complete. I do not see any reference to `.autocomplete()`. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty this is my whole code. I don't have yet the suggestion with another suggestion referring to the top part of the photo because I don't really have experience working with json file or api this is the first the time, all of my works are directly fetching data to the database, but I'm trying my best right now to learn it and to figure out how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally follow what the issue is as your reduce logic seams to work, I wonder if its how you are then mapping it in your auto complete, you are using "lookup" but if you use "source" and map the array so that it has label and value, I believe it should work as you desire, here is an example using you array but note how I'm mapping it to have label and value, I then just tweaked your autocomplete slightly

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "location": "El Nido",
    "property": "El Nido Hotel 1",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1s1GOpqujbUbBXaSde5He29jO0aWWrK9C",
    "body": "This is Elnido Hotel 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "location": "El Nido",
    "property": "El Nido Hotel 2",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Kdyrq5qLXgL8Cwuz1Ekz6gUyj7qhczHp",
    "body": "This is Elnido Hotel 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "location": "El Nido",
    "property": "El Nido Hotel 3",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=16fiBYsg-9o9kPhkzMaeFU5J2mH9Lk4be",
    "body": "This is Elnido Hotel 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "location": "Boracay",
    "property": "Boracay Hotel 1",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=13XG6Vjr2wbqwxfO_HG1K1NhFJPzsfG_K",
    "body": "This is Boracay Hotel 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "location": "Boracay",
    "property": "Boracay Hotel 2",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1IMg1e8f8b_znWs_57VrNzN6RumbWpadm",
    "body": "This is Boracay Hotel 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "location": "Davao",
    "property": "Davao Hotel 1",
    "url": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1fOiTOp5AEjJf0-r75S8C4Bz4im24LssS",
    "body": "This is Davao Hotel 1"
  }
]

var uniqueCity = jQuery.map(Array.from(data.reduce((map, obj) =>
  map.set(obj.location, obj), new Map()).values()), function(x, i) {
  return {
    value: x.location,
    label: x.property,
    id: x.id,
    body: x.body,
    url: x.url,
  };
})


console.log(uniqueCity)

$("#destination").autocomplete({
  source: uniqueCity,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $("#destination").val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#destination").val(ui.item.label);
    console.log(ui.item.body)
    console.log(ui.item.id)
    console.log(ui.item.label)
    console.log(ui.item.value)
    console.log(ui.item.url)
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="destination">
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Patrick, your answer helps me to solve my problem for removing duplicate suggestion. apologize for my code because this is my first time working with json file or api. All of my works are directly fetching data from database. Thank you so much.

Comment: thats ok glad you were able to work it out, I know its not easy learning something new on your own but keep at it and your get their ;)